# How can sort data second table from first table in c#

Tags: c#

I am currently working in c# project. I have a table named `tbl1` which have only one column named `Beta` and I have another table named `tbl2` which also have only one column named `Alpha`.

I want to compare both the table. If I click the button then if the second table has value

> "A, D, R, B, A, E, B, Y"

match's with the first table value i.e.

> "A, E, B"

then the resultant value should show in gridview and the result should be

> "A, B, E, B".

Comment: Please, add some of your current code and maybe a description of what you have tried to solve this problem, so that others can help you better. Also, I am not sure what you want to do, could you please state this more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this in C#:

```
        var tableA = new List<string> {"A","D","R","B","A","E","B","Y"};
        var tableB = new List<string> { "A","E","B" };

        var result = tableA.Intersect(tableB).ToList();

        return tableA.Where(x=> result.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

Replace the hardcoded tableA and tableB with your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using some DB engine like MS SQL if working with c# so in this case, intersect clause will you give the required result.

Syntax:

```
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions]
INTERSECT
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions];
```

So query could be like:

```
SELECT Beta
FROM tbl1
INTERSECT
SELECT Alpha
FROM tbl2
```

PS: There must be same number of expressions in both SELECT statements.

The corresponding expressions must have the same data type in the SELECT statements